# How to rotate truck image used in CCSprite on touch in iOS objective c?

Tags: ios, ccsprite

we are trying to update old maze game in iOS objective-c
I don't know any thing about sprite(games) used in iOS.
I am trying to do hit n trial to move truck in maze game,
Truck image is used in CCsprite,So how to rotate truck image used in CCSprite on touch to every position.

```
_player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"trolley_ipad.png"];


- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
```

Comment: In order to receive  good responses you will need to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You set an (anchor) point to rotate around:

```
_player.anchorPoint = cpp(anchorX, anchorY);
```

and rotate it:

```
_player.rotation = 90;
```